# How to remove a part of all strings in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want split array value .

for example

`gUser[1] = CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962`

`gUser[2] = CAR.PORSCHE.911.2001`

I want get string only `BENZ.CLASS.1962` and `PORSCHE.911.2001`

How to split array value on java script?

@update.

not always `CAR` string.
so, not use substring.

Comment: you want to get a substring of the elements.

Comment: @davidxxx not use substring, because not always `CAR` string

Comment: so you need to split it from the first . (dot)? @hyunwooks

Comment: @john is possible use split on array?

Comment: You can use it on a string. (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: @john I know use split. but split is only use string. is right?

Comment: Yes, traverse the array using a for loop. Afterwards use use string operations to get the desired value. `gUser[index].split('.').slice(1).join('.')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map to access each string in array then use replace. Use a regex to match string before '.' and replace only the first match, like this:

```js
  var gUser = ['CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962', 'CAR.PORSCHE.911.2001'];

  var gUserModified = gUser.map(function(v){
        return v.replace(/[^\.]+\./, '');
  });
  console.log(gUserModified);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it with dot then slice it and join it with dot

```js
var gUser =[];
gUser[1] = "CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962";

gUser[2] = "CAR.PORSCHE.911.2001";

console.log(gUser[1].split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
console.log(gUser[2].split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's not clear if the array is a string array

If it is a string array you can do:

ES6+: `gUser.map((user)=>{return user.split("CAR.")[1]})`

ES5: `gUser.map(function(user){return user.split("CAR.")[1]});`

Answer (score 0):

The below code is not tested but should probably work, with maybe minor tweaks

```js
var splitStr = ''
var correctCarArr = []
for(let i = 0; i < gUser.length; i++){
  splitStr = gUser[i].split('.')
  let temp = ''
  for(let j = 1; j < splitStr.length; j++){
    temp += splitStr[j]
  }
  correctCarArr.push(temp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var gUser = [];
gUser[1] = "CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962";
var gu1 = gUser[1].split(".");
gu1.shift();
console.log(gu1.join("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier split then shift the array to remove the first item like this:

```js
gUser = ["CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962"];
var benz = gUser[0].split(".");
benz.shift();
alert(benz.join('.'));
```

There are other options from shift like slice(1) but In terms of performance, shift is apparently faster https://jsperf.com/shift-pop-vs-slice/4

Answer (score 0):

So here is the way without using any `regex` by only using string and array methods.

```js
const gUser = ['CAR.BENZ.CCLASS.1962', 'CAR.PORSCHE.911.2001', 'XYZAB.PORSCHE.YSA.2021']

for (let i = 0; i < gUser.length; i++) {
  console.log('Required String: ', gUser[i].split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
}
```

What we do is, we split the string into parts where `.` is encountered.

`gUser[0].split('.')` returns `['CAR', 'BENZ', 'CCLASS', '1962']`

Later when `slice(1)` is called, the zeroth element of array is chopped off and will return `['BENZ', 'CCLASS', '1962']`

And finally using `join('.')`, we merge the array elements to a single string with a `.` between each element, which returns `BENZ.CCLASS.1962`

---

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something Like This

```
`for(let index = 0; index < gUser.length; index++) {
    console.log(gUser[index].split('.').splice(0, 1).join('.'));
}`
```

I haven't tested it. Please check and let me know